# Variable created on the heap, 2 pointers pointing to same variable have different addresses?

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

I just learned the difference between the stack and the heap. After creating a function which will dynamically allocate memory on the heap for me, I return the pointer and display (in and out of the function) the address and value of each pointer.

The values are the same, which I expected, but the addresses to the same chunk of memory on the heap are different, which I did NOT expect.

Why? Shouldn't pHeap2 and pTemp point to the same address?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* intOnHeap(); // returns an int on the heap
int main()
{
 int* pHeap = new int; // new operator allocates memory on the heap and returns its address
       // 'new int' allocates enough memory on heap for one int and returns the address on the heap for that chunk of memory
       // 'int* pHeap' is a local pointer which points to the newly allocated chunk of memory
 *pHeap = 10;
 cout << "*pHeap: " << *pHeap << "\n\n";

 int* pHeap2 = intOnHeap();
 cout << "pHeap2:\n-----------" << endl;
 cout << "Address:\t" << &pHeap2 << "\n";
 cout << "Value:\t\t" << *pHeap2 << "\n\n";

 cout << "Freeing memory pointed to by pHeap.\n\n";
 delete pHeap;

 cout << "Freeing memory pointed to by pHeap2.\n\n";
 delete pHeap2;

// get rid of dangling pointers
    pHeap = 0;
    pHeap2 = 0;

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

int* intOnHeap()
{
 int* pTemp = new int(20);
 cout << "pTemp:\n-----------" << endl;
 cout << "Address:\t" << &pTemp << "\n";
 cout << "Value:\t\t" << *pTemp << "\n\n";
 return pTemp;
}
```

**Output:**

```
*pHeap: 10

pTemp:
-----------
Address:        0042FBB0
Value:          20

pHeap2:
-----------
Address:        0042FCB4
Value:          20

Freeing memory pointed to by pHeap.

Freeing memory pointed to by pHeap2.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reporting the address of the pointers, not the address that the pointer is pointing to. Of course the address of the pointer will be different for `pTemp` and `pHeap2`; these are different pointers that happen to be pointing to the same address in memory. Remove the `&` prefixing `pTemp` and `pHeap2` to see the results that you are expecting.

The picture is something like this:

```
0042FBB0           0042FBC0     0042FCB4
------------       ------       ------------
| 0042FBC0 |------>| 20 |<------| 0042FBC0 |
------------       ------       ------------
pTemp                           pHeap2
```

Here you have that `&pTemp` is `0042FBB0` and `&pHeap2` is `0042FCB4`. I made up an address for the address that `pTemp` and `pHeap2` are pointing to (of course, the results could vary from run to run anyway) and if you remove the `&` prefixing `pTemp` and `pHeap2` then you would see `0042FBC0` printed instead in each case.

Comment: Dude, thanks so much. I guess I knew that &var gives the address of THAT VARIABLE, but I forgot that pointers are going to have their own addresses, and POINT to DIFFERENT ADDRESSES. I modified my code and added: 

cout << "Pointing to:\t" << pHeap2 << endl;
cout << "Pointing to:\t" << pTemp << endl;

in their respective areas, and now I get what I was looking for! To get the address it is pointing to, I don't use the reference operator, because thats gonna be the address OF THAT variable :) Thanks Jason!!

Comment: @shadowprotocol: Yeah, it's that `&pTemp` and `&pHeap2` are pointers to pointers and those are the addresses above the left and right boxes in the picture.

Comment: Why can't I add formatting and paragraphs to my comments? That is terribly ugly, above.

Comment: @shadowprotocol: Paragraphs and many other types of spacing are ignored by the comment parser. You can wrap code in back ticks `\`` to format in a monospace font.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `pTemp` and `pHeap2` should be the same.  But `&pTemp` and `&pHeap2` are different.  This is because the `&` operator returns a pointer to it's operand.  So `pTemp` is a pointer to an `int`, while `&pTemp` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`&pHeap2` doesn't return the value of the pointer, it returns the address of the pointer. That's because of the `&`, which in this context means "the address of".

i.e. at 0042FCB4 in memory, there's a pointer pointing to 0042FBB0 (i.e. in a big-endian environment, you'd see 00 42 FB B0 at 0042FCB4).